# Adding keepframe(false) to core swatch img

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0

Currently, I am using keepFrame(false) on the product images of my category listings page to remove the white space Magento automatically adds. How can I also pass keepframe(false) to the images that are swapped out by the core swatches? The white space does not return when swatches are clicked?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I never found a solution. I did a quick fix by re-enabling keepframe and just cropping the product images as I needed.

Comment: I think the problem is that the image is then reloaded with javascript so there's no way to repass the keepframe parameters in PHP. I think I may completely stop Magento from adding whitespace in the core. That should hopefully fix it.